# How do I put a specific string from an array that came from a file in PHP?

Tags: php

Hi I have been doing this project for almost a month now. Is there's anyway I can store the value of the next string after the searched string in the list of array?

For example:

Deviceid.txt content is:

```
Created:21/07/2016 1:50:53; Lat:30.037853; Lng:31.113798; Altitude:79; Speed:0; Course:338; Type:Gps;
Created:21/07/2016 1:49:53; Lat:30.037863; Lng:31.113733; Altitude:60; Speed:0; Course:338; Type:Gps;
```

Here is my sample php coding

```
$file_handle = fopen("data/deviceid.txt", "r");
while (!feof($file_handle)) {
    $line = fgets($file_handle);
    array_push($a,$line);
}

$searchword = 'Lat';
$matches = array_filter($a, function($var) use ($searchword) {
        return preg_match("/\b$searchword\b/i", $var);
    });
print_r($matches);
fclose($file_handle);
```

Matches Data:
[0] = 30.037853
[1] = 30.037863

Comment: what do you mean next string after the search? could you please make your requirements a bit more clearer?

Comment: Hi I did rephrase some words I wanted to make the next string to be the data to be stored in the array.

Comment: show the expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After parsing the file with the code below, you can use [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) (php v5.5.0+) to get all values from a specific key, like so:

```
array_column($parsed, 'Lat');
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 30.037853
    [1] => 30.037863
)
```

See it in action [here](https://eval.in/610549).

---

And here is the code to **parse** the content of the file:

```
// $a = each line of the file, just like you're doing

$a = array_filter($a); // remove empty lines

$parsed = array();

foreach($a as $v1){
    $a1 = explode(';', $v1);
    $tmp = array();
    foreach($a1 as $v2){
        $t2 = explode(':', $v2);
        if(count($t2) > 1){
            $tmp[trim(array_shift($t2))] = trim(  implode(':', $t2)  );
        }
    }
    $parsed[] = $tmp;
}
```

---

This is the structure of `$parsed`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Created] => 21/07/2016 1:50:53
            [Lat] => 30.037853
            [Lng] => 31.113798
            [Altitude] => 79
            [Speed] => 0
            [Course] => 338
            [Type] => Gps
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Created] => 21/07/2016 1:49:53
            [Lat] => 30.037863
            [Lng] => 31.113733
            [Altitude] => 60
            [Speed] => 0
            [Course] => 338
            [Type] => Gps
        )

)
```

See the code in action [here](https://eval.in/610540).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a quick regex that can help you pull the field names and values from each line.

You may try with this:

```
$re = "/((?P<fieldname>[^\\:]*)\\:(?P<fieldvalue>[^\\;]*); *)/"; 
$str = "Created:21/07/2016 1:50:53; Lat:30.037853; Lng:31.113798; Altitude:79; Speed:0; Course:338; Type:Gps;"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Do a `print_r` of `$matches` to inspect the results.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

After your `array_filter`, iterate through your matches and apply a more specific regex to each line:

```
$lats = array();
foreach ($matches as $line)
{
    $match = array();
    preg_match("/\b$searchword:([\d\.]+);/i", $var, $match); 
    $lats[] = $match[1];
}
print_r($lats);
```

The variable `$match` will be populated with the full regex match at index 0, [and the parenthesized match at index 1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).